# Нужно найти в строке множество букв

Tags: java

есть строка `"kldm"` и в ней нужно проверить, есть ли буквы из `"l,p,o,k,j,s,h,r"`, думаю реализовать `.contains`, но как сделать, чтобы он не 1 букву искал, и не слово, а `"l,p,o,k,j,s,h,r"` - все эти буквы.

Comment: Искать по очереди.

Comment: искомые буквы залить в хешсет в виде чаров (символов), разложить на символы строку, в которой нужно искать и проверять наличие каждого символа в ранее созданном хешсете. это быстрее поиска итератором, поскольку сет использует дерево для поиска

Answer (score 1):

С помощью регулярного выражения:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean notFound = true;
        // сюда вставить строку в которой будем искать
        String input = "kldm";
        // сюда вставить регулярное выражение
        String regex = "[lpokjshr]";
        try {
            System.out.println("Проверяемая строка: " + input);
            System.out.println("Регулярное выражение: " + regex);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
            while (m.find()) {
                notFound = false;
                System.out.println("Найдено [" + m.group() + "] начало в "
                        + (m.start() + 1) + " позиции и конец в " + m.end() + " позиции.");
            }
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
            System.err.println("Bad regex: " + pse.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Description: " + pse.getDescription());
            System.err.println("Index: " + pse.getIndex());
            System.err.println("Incorrect pattern: " + pse.getPattern());
        }
        if (notFound) System.out.println("Ничего не найдено!!!");
    }
}
```

Результат:

Проверяемая строка: kldm

Регулярное выражение: [lpokjshr]

Найдено [k] начало в 1 позиции и конец в 1 позиции.

Найдено [l] начало в 2 позиции и конец в 2 позиции.